# How to identify an fso folder object as a shortcut

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a script (in an Access database) that recursively goes through a file directory and lists all the subfolders.  It normally works fine - but someone (not me and I cannot delete it) put a shortcut to the top of the directory in a lower level folder.  So the folder looks like it contains itself and the recursive procedure doesn't terminate.

For the code section that begins with "for each folder in flist", how can I identify the folder as a shortcut so I can skip it in my process?

The two code segments are

```
Function directory()
ftype = InputBox("file type, or '*'")
recursive = InputBox("Recursive y/n")
CurrentDb().Execute "delete * from [directory folders]"
CurrentDb().Execute "delete * from [directory]"
Source = get_folder()
SQL = "Insert into [directory folders] ([top]) Select '" & Source & "'"
CurrentDb().Execute SQL
If recursive = "y" Then x = Directory_folders(Source, Source)
x = Directory_files(ftype)
MsgBox "Done"
End Function
```

and

```
Function Directory_folders(Top, Source)
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
n = 1 + Len(Top)
Set Flist = FSO.GetFolder(Source).SubFolders
For Each Folder In Flist
    P = Folder.Path
    SQL = "Insert into [directory folders] ([top], [folder]) Select '" & Top & "','" & Mid(P, n) & "'"
    CurrentDb().Execute SQL
    x = Directory_folders(Top, P)
    Next Folder

End Function
```

The last function, directory_files(), isn't shown here but uses the folder list to create a table of all the files in each folder.  It doesn't even get called until after the folder list is created, and isn't part of the current problem.

Comment: In my quick testing the `SubFolders` collection doesn't include shortcuts.

Comment: It's probably not a shortcut, but one of those: [There are three types of file links supported in the NTFS file system: hard links, junctions, and symbolic links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Andre451 - I've never used either of those other two types...  I guess the easy workaround is to exclude the shortcut based on its name/path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Alias flag in the Attributes of the folder:

```
For Each Folder In Flist
  If (Folder.Attributes And Alias) = 0 Then
      ' do stuff, this is not an alias folder
  End If
Next
```

p.s.: same technique can be applied as well to any normal file to check wherther a file is normal or shortcut or symbolic link...